# Using STS 4 IDE Java compiler error preference Empty Statement is ignored

Tags: spring-tools-4

In the Preference dialog the selection for Java->Compiler->Error/Warnings, changing the option for "Empty Statement" in the Potential Programming Problems section to any value other than Error seems to be ignored.  I have tried changing the option at both global and project levels with the same result.  Regardless of the option value anytime a line is ended with a double semicolon it is reported as a Syntax Error.

Is this a known problem and is there a solution or work-around.  I am running into this problem in code that I have no authorization to change.

Comment: A double semicolon is reported as "unnecessary semicolon" if that "empty statement" check is set to info, warning or error and ignored when set to ignore. Sounds like a config issue in your project and/or workspace, but I have no idea what exactly this might be. The general mechanism seems to work. If the error persists, I would recommend to create a small sample project with project-specific settings and attach that to a bug report at Eclipse.